# Converting JSON to Usable object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have some JSON with two parameters expressed as

```
{"pushid":"35336165333161382d646338302d346665302d626236312d303763313435663036656131","count":1}
```

I'm trying to get access to the "pushid" and the "count" as usable elements, either in an object, an array or a map, and am a little confused as to how to do that.

When I call JSON.parse(json) it returns undefined, and so I assume that it's already an object. However, when I try to use json[1] it returns the second character of the whole thing (which in this case is "). How do I make an object

```
var obj = {pushId: SOME_STRING, count: SOME_INT)?
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Show your full code. `JSON.parse({a: "a"})` gives you `{a: "a"}` and not `undefined`.

Comment: It should be object in an instance, as if you set `var data = yourJsonString;` and when you `console.log(data) => object` or `console.log(data.count) => 1` and you cant use json[1] on an object, since 1 is not a key, if the data is a full string '{"key": "value"}' a json[1] will return " since its the 2nd char

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you describe: http://jsbin.com/cixesog/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering:

```
var jsonString = '{"pushid":"35336165333161382d646338302d346665302d626236312d303763313435663036656131","count":1}';
```

You can do:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(jsonObj.pushid); // 3533...
console.log(jsonObj['pushid']); // 3533...
console.log(jsonObj.count); // 1
console.log(jsonObj['count']); // 1
console.log(jsonObj[0]); // undefined
console.log(jsonObj[1]); // undefined
```

Comment: @Quentin you are here all the time.. what do you do  for living :P

Comment: @Quentin Check updated answer. It working for me on Chrome.

Comment: @AlexandreThebaldi — That just means you can't produce the problem, which isn't an answer.

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. I was just making a really stupid error. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is already an object so you don't have to parse it.    {"pushid":"35336165333161382d646338302d346665302d626236312d303763313435663036656131","count":1}

All you have to do is now assign it to what ever variable you want.

```
let data = {"pushid":"35336165333161382d646338302d346665302d626236312d303763313435663036656131","count":1};

console.log("pushid : " + data["pushid"]);
pushid : 35336165333161382d646338302d346665302d626236312d303763313435663036656131

console.log("count : " + data["count"]);
count : 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean, that number is too long for JS to represent in it's 64 bit floating point internal representation, but you can try to parse the base16 repr with

`parseInt(obj.pushid, 16);`

Comment: it's alpha numeric

Comment: The question is asking about parsing the JSON, not about converting the string value of one of the properties of the object into a number